# Can I put a box fan in a chimney to help circulate out hot summer air?

Tags: ventilation, fans, cooling, chimney, heat

I have a classic brick chimney for a wood fireplace only (i.e. no hot water tank or other things sharing the stack).

In peak summer heat, the interior of the upstairs is well above the exterior temperature in the evenings for many hours.

I am wondering if a box fan pointing up the stack would be effective for pushing air out of the house.

It would be particularly convenient from a security point of view since the chimney is an existing hole in the structure, and "secure". We could even leave it running unattended 24x7.

Is this a bad idea? I'm OK if it's less efficient for some reason than a window or doorway placement. But if it would be completely ineffective, then, that would be a problem.

Comment: Warm air rises, so the warmest air will be near the ceiling.  The opening for the fireplace is at/near the floor.

Comment: Do you have any windows in that space that you could install a window-fan unit?  They are purpose built for installing in an operable window, but depending upon the style of window they may or may not fit.   Also, remember any air you expel from that space is going get replaced, perhaps drawing hot air into other parts of the home.

Comment: You would be bushing air through a long, rough duct . It will have much more resistance than a window vent.  There are also fans with shutters that go into a wall if you are concerned about security ( fan pushes shutter open , gravity closes it ),

Comment: it's not a bad or harmful idea, but it might not be very effective. The cost of trying is low so just give it a shot and see what you think.

Comment: It is a slick idea.  I am a "whole house fan" groupie and this sounds like what you are trying to do, but without cutting a hole in the roof.  I like it and you have got me thinking now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A cheap box fan will not push air through any enclosed structure like a chimney unless it is sealed into the opening so air will not just recirculate around the blade.  Also, a fan used to move air through a duct or space must have a venturi built into the fans construction so that the air is displaced and does not just recirculate.  To understand the fan's construction, search for whole house exhaust fans or exhaust fan venturi. The hole the fan blade sits in does not allow for air to recirculate back to the fans inlet just to be recirculated. Hope this helps.

Comment: +1 for acknowledging short circulating air in the chimney. And, the room will never cool down less than the existing outside air temperature that you’re bringing in as “make up air”. That’s why room fans are so popular. Having air blow across your skin (even though it’s warm air) cools the body.

Answer (score 0):

I submitted an edit to the main answer to address the Venturi issue with a box fan. But depending on your budget, there are better ways to achieve what you are trying to do. Two of them will use a chimney, some of them will do so in a way that is inherently a little unsafe unless you’re super careful and possibly so even if you are.

1. If you’re obsessed with using your existing fireplace chimney, and assuming the outside air is higher temp than the inside (which would result in reverse stack effect and your house smelling like creosote at best and getting filled with unswept soot at worst) you could use a small blower fan like so, and get an pipe adapter that will fit snugly into your damper opening. Those vary so much there is no way to say whether this will be easy, but if it’s best case scenario you have a prefab fireplace with a top mounted pivot damper. In which case you pull a chain, put your four inch or whatever pipe up into the smoke chamber, then seal off everything but your chain and exit pipe with plastic or cardboard or whatever. You shouldn’t have to worry about water in this case because that kind of damper on a prefab usually has a built in rain guard.
2. You’re obsessed with the chimney, don’t care if it’s the fireplace,
   and your heater burns shit without a high efficiency label (meaning
   it has its own chimney of some sort). This is in some ways a best
   case scenario. In some ways a quick way to kill your whole family if
   you forget to reverse your modifications and/or do it incorrectly
   come winter.

   If you already have a gas furnace, particularly if you have a short
   house or live in a climate where the outdoor air isn’t terribly cold
   100% of the time you might be running your furnace, you should
   already have a fan connected directly to your chimney. It’s called a
   draft inducer and is wired directly to your furnace. It’s designed
   to activate just prior to the burners kicking on. This ensure that
   there is positive draft so you’re not pushing CO gas into your house
   while the furnace warms up enough that natural draft kicks in.

   Now, draft inducers have less power than a really good PC fan in
   terms of CFM. Along with the “modifying this is potentially fatal”
   situation, your better bet is to get a high power fan that can fit
   to a 4-6” pipe and hook that to a T connector in your stove pipe.
   You’ll want one of these
   (https://www.supplyhouse.com/Fantech-RSK6-RSK-Series-6-Duct-Backdraft-Damper)
   between your blower and your T pipe to prevent flue gases from
   escaping if you keep it connected in winter.
3. Just get an HRV (if you live in a climate that is very cold in
   winter but not humid in summer) or ERV (if it’s not that cold in
   winter and humid in summer) or both (if it’s winter cold and summer
   humid). You can get whole house ones at somewhat of a cost in terms
   of the device and your labor, or you can get single room ones for a
   few hundred bucks. They will ventilate and exchange temperature
   (Heat Recovery Ventilator/HRV) or temp + humidity (Energy Recovery
   Ventilator/ERV) between the intake and exhaust streams. The right
   one for your climate will result in substantial energy savings. But
   an ERV will freeze up in winter if it’s too cold, but an HRV will do
   nothing to remove intake humidity in the summer which will mean your
   AC works overtime or your comfort level decreases.

   These won’t work on your existing chimneys, but your existing
   chimney is a pretty shitty tool for ventilation without huge
   temperature differences. It’s designed to work because the there is
   always slight airflow from ground to roof through the stack when the
   temps are higher inside than outside. But you only get big airflow
   with big temperature differences. And if you’re going to use powered
   ventilation anyway, the chimney is sort of redundant.

If you don’t care about ventilation efficiency and just want to move air, put a fan in an upstairs window and open a downstairs window. Make sure there is an unobstructed path between the two (and close your vents, if you don’t want some of your nice airflow to make vent residents more comfortable) and you will get what you want.

So… yeah. Source: I was a chimney sweep for several years, and have been considering building a very stupid chimney system for the passive cooling of a large PC. That would be a good idea if designed properly, as the waste heat from the PC will create a meaningful temperature difference to power stack effect, so long as the stack is tall enough.

Comment: There are a _lot_ of words here, but they're hard to follow. "a me of them will do so in a way that is inherently a little unsafe" is confusing, but "inherently a little unsafe" is a red-flag around here. We tend towards recommending _strict_ compliance with codes and safety procedures since people in general tend to fudge a bit. Always assume that people will make the _worst_ possible decisions with the info you share, not the best decisions, and you'll probably be right 90% of the time.